# Not receiving json response from PHP and no error in PHP error log or in the console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I am just a little bit frustrated and also I hate Javascript in any form but please someone can tell me why is this not working? :C But If I mess up something or I just return a simple string then its working. Its only when I try to access sg from $decoded.

PHP

```
header("Content-Type: application/json"); // Setting content type to application/json

function JsonError($msg1, $msg2) // Error handler
{
    die(json_encode(array("error" => $msg1, "errorMessage" => $msg2)));
}

if(strcasecmp($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], "POST") != 0) // Throw error if request is not POST
{
    JsonError("exception", "Not valid request method!");
}

$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : "";
if(strcasecmp($contentType, "application/json") != 0) // Throw error if content is application/json
{
    JsonError("exception", "Not valid content type!");
}

$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input")); // Getting rid of any whitespace and getting that juicy json content
$decoded = json_decode($content, true); // Decoding json content

die(json_encode(array("status" => "FUCK ME", "title" => $decoded[0]["uri"])));
```

JS

```
// Function to handle errors and responses
function HandleAjax(resp) 
{

    console.log(resp);

    if(typeof(resp) == "string")
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);

    if (resp.error)
    {
        alert(resp.error + " " + resp.errorMessage);
    }
}
/////

//////////// TEST SECTION /////////////////

$("#submit").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($("#val1").val());

    var data = [
        {"uri":"utalasdata"},
        {"currpass":$('#utalas .paytoform input[name=currpass]').val()},
        {"payto":$('#utalas .paytoform input[name=payto]').val()},
        {"amount":$('#utalas .paytoform input[name=amount]').val()}
    ];

    $.post("ajax.php", JSON.stringify(data) , HandleAjax, "application/json");
});

//////////////////////////////////////////
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="subme">
</from>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

Thanks for everyone in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your browser's developer console or network tab to see what's being returned and if there are any error messages?

Comment: It's probably just an aside, but that is some *interesting* JSON. Are you deliberately creating different objects for each property? Usually these would be 1 object (e.g. `var data = {"uri":"utalasdata", "currpass": $('#utalas .paytoform input[name=currpass]').val(), "payto": $('#utalas .paytoform input[name=payto]').val(), "amount": $('#utalas .paytoform input[name=amount]').val()};`)

Comment: @aynber yes I did there is none :C

Comment: I suspect you are generating an exception and is not correctly interpreted as json output.
add at line 2 this
file_put_contents('/tmp/app_debug', json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
so you can see what's actually is going to be processed
or you can add the entire block into a try/catch to see if an exception is being generated

Comment: @Luke I was frustrated I was just trying things

Comment: Is there anything in the Network tab? Do you see the request and the response it's sending back?

Comment: @aynber in the network tab yeah there is a request with status 200 and also response from ajax.php with status 200

Comment: @d3javu999 "[{\"uri\":\"utalasdata\"},{\"currpass\":\"test\"},{\"payto\":\"test\"},{\"amount\":\"test\"}]"

Answer (score 0):

this will not solve your problem but will help you understanding what is happening

```
function JsonError($msg1, $msg2) // Error handler
{
    die(json_encode(array("error" => $msg1, "errorMessage" => $msg2)));
}

header("Content-Type: application/json"); // Setting content type to application/json
try {
    if(strcasecmp($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], "POST") != 0) // Throw error if request is not POST
    {
        JsonError("exception", "Not valid request method!");
    }

    $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : "";
    if(strcasecmp($contentType, "application/json") != 0)
    {
        JsonError("exception", "Not valid content type!");
    }

    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $decoded = json_decode($content, true); // Decoding json content

    die(json_encode(array("status" => "error", "title" => $decoded[0]["uri"])));
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => $e->getMessage()));
    file_put_contents('/tmp/app_debug', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: There is no exception because I am not receiving anything in the log file. But still no response in the browser. But in the REST API client I am receiving the correct output.

Comment: ok so don't do  data: JSON.stringify(data), but jus data: data, and you should be able to get your values in php by doing $decoded["uri"]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I changed my Jquery code to this...

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: handleAjax
        });
```

Funny :C